# Is there any API to get path "C:\Documents and Settings" in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, api, document

Is there any API to get path : "C:\Documents and Settings" in windows in c++?

not: C:\Documents and Settings\brianfu\My Documents.

Many Thanks!

Thanks for luke's solution:

```
GetProfilesDirectory
```

it works!

Comment: I'm not seeing which CSIDL corresponds to that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx).  Perhaps MS doesn't think it good practice to have access to that path.

Comment: me too... But I need to remove it from my own folder tree.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you need to do with it? Because it's likely going to break in more complex environments, such as corporate Windows environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GetProfilesDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762278.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Windows Vista, this can be retrieve via [GetProfilesDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762278%28VS.85%29.aspx).

In Windows Vista+, this can be done via the [`SHGetKnownFolderIDList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions using the [FOLDERID_UserProfiles KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) constant.

Answer (score 1):

Get the home path (%HOMEPATH% environment variable), and then go one folder up (removing the user name).

Answer (score 1):

It's available via the `ProfilesDirectory` key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

(Note that on Win7 (and Vista?) this will be `C:\Users` not `C:\Documents and Settings`.